# How can I clear the "authentication cache" in Windows 7 to a password protected samba share?

Tags: windows, authentication, samba, cache

I have a Linux samba server and have explicitly listed users that can access the folder.

I have successfully congfigured Samba to require a username and password when accessing the share from windows (using the smbpasswd, etc.).

But now I want to force clear the auth cache on the windows machine. Such as when I go to a colleague's computer, I use my account to access a file in the protected share, but then before I leave his computer, i'll want to make sure the authorization cache is cleared so he cannot access that folder with my credentials.

I found the command to use in the windows command prompt on google a couple of weeks ago but silly me I didn't save it...

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Oh, Samba is configured as a workgroup and not a domain (if that helps)   - so windows users do NOT log into a domain on start up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
net session \\samba.server.ip.address /delete
```

You can also use:

```
net use
```

To give a list of active sessions and to ensure that you've deleted them afterwards.

Comment: A session does not exist with that computer name. But it exists obviously. Tried both IP and name.

Comment: `net use \\computername /delete` worked to delete it, but the samba credentials were still present, even after restarting explorer from the task manager

Answer (score 25):

Try this

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager

Click on the arrow beside the cred you wish to delete

than click on remove from vault

Comment: This helped me where the accepted answer did not. Thank you!

Comment: Faster way: Win+R and paste
%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{1206F5F1-0569-412C-8FEC-3204630DFB70}

Comment: I am still able to delete and write file on my network after doing this.

Answer (score 24):

Incomplete advice.
The answer is:

As previously mentioned clear all entries in credentials manager, close any open share explorer windows and/or all applications utilizing the share.

THEN

Open services manager. Find the "Workstation" service and restart it.

Comment: Agreed - this is the correct answer.

Comment: @endolith Communities are different. It's ok here.

Answer (score 3):

How to Disconnect\logout from Samba Share on Windows 10.

RUN cmd as user(not administrator)!!!

watch yours connection

```
net use
```

delete all connection(logout)

```
net use * /delete

net use * /d

net use \\10.10.10.5 /delete
```

delete all saved network passwords

```
klist purge
```

or run utilities

```
control keymgr.dll
```

or run

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

Answer (score 3):

If deleting credentials from Credential Manager does not help then you have two more options:
1) Open Run and execute `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr` and look for addresses you would like to remove. 
 2) If CMD's `net use` does not show anything then open `cmd` as administrator and execute:

```sh
net stop workstation /y
net start workstation
```

This should clear the cache. Last option always works for me.